# How to convert pipe delimited file with multi thousand records into XML in mule

Tags: java, xml, file, mule

I have a `file inbound endpoint` where a pipe delimited file will come in. The first line of the file is header and rest are records. On an average there would be 40K records making file size close to 7MB. I need to convert this file into XML structure (headers from file are not same as XML elements).

What is a good way to convert this file to XML? I wrote a `component` which takes `input stream`, read file line by line, tokenize it, create and write to an XML file. But in that case I am keeping file connection open for long time and I would have to take care about closing file stream and moving the file for backup.

Wondering what can be other way of doing it? Has anyone used `Data Mapper` for similar purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mule docs for DataMapper state that "DataMapper can parse a 500 MB CSV file using only about 75 MB of RAM" if you set the "streaming" property in DataMapper configuration. Pipe delemited counts as CSV, as you can configure the delimiter. You can also set it to ignore the header row. I would go for DataMapper, post another question if something fails, and only revert to a custom component when all hope is lost.

Comment: Hi Anton - I was able to run data mapper in Mule studio but when I try to run in standalone mule enterprise runtime, I see following error:` Data Mapper runtime is not installed on the mule runtime. (java.lang.RuntimeException)
  com.mulesoft.mule.module.datamapper.clover.CloverEngineConfig:61 (null)`. Any idea? Appreciate your help!

Comment: If you have the EE license, ask from Mule Support.

Comment: I will but thought if anybody else faced same issue

Comment: If anybody is still reading this ... "DataMapper is deprecated as of Mule runtime 3.7.0 and superseded by DataWeave." (from https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/including-the-datamapper-plugin)